# Mask/Change IP address while running Python script

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website, run a search and retrieve the results. I've checked with the website and I'm allowed to do so. The problem is that after a few searches it temporarily blocks me and I have to wait a while before I can continue scraping. This is causing major delays. So I wanted to know if there is a way I could maybe mask my ip and keep changing it when it blocks me? I'm running my script in python using selenium. I have no idea if this can be done, would be really cool if it could though.

Comment: Your IP is how the server's TCP socket knows where to send the replies. So, unless you own a bunch of other IPs and can set up proxies on them, or can use publicly-open proxies that have the same effect, no, you can't do this.

Comment: Also, even if the website says you're allowed to scrape their site, I'd be willing to bet that you're _not_ allowed to deliberately fake out their rate-limiting system.

Comment: use a rotating proxy

Comment: To avoid being blocked, add an IP rotation and captcha resolver layer to your scraper. This article assisted me in dealing with IP blocking. Hope this helps. Cheers!
https://medium.com/@scraperguy/this-could-be-the-answer-to-your-web-scraping-problems-66c88e775c42